# Display only 1 element when it's a repetition

Tags: python, list, inverse

I would like print a result without duplicate with my multiplication

Here an example :

```
5*3*2=30
2*3*5=30
5*2*3=30
3*2*5=30
.....
```

All these element are from my list that I browse and you can see it's always  =30

So I would like display only the first element  (5*3*2) and not others because they are the same.

To be more accurate, here an example what I have :

```
list = ['5*3*2','5*2*3','2*3*5','2*5*3']

for i in list:       
     if eval(i) == eval(i)+1 ??? (I dont know how to say the next element)
            print(eval(i))
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: `eval(i)` equals 30 but `eval(i)+1` equals 31. Surely that's not what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with `not in` will help you.

```
#python 3.5.2
list = ['5*3*2','5*2*3','6*9','2*3*5','2*5*3','8*3','9*6']
elm = []
for i in list:   
    elm_value = eval(i)
    if elm_value not in elm:
        elm.append(elm_value)
print(elm)
```

**DEMO:** https://rextester.com/QKV22875

Answer (score 1):

The comparison:

```
eval(i) == eval(i)+1
```

Will compare if the the number `i` is *equal* to `i + 1`, which will always return `False`. I'm sure you mean to use `i` as an index and simply wanted to compare if the current element is equal to the next element in the list. However, doing this doesn't really keep track of duplicates, since you have to consider everything else in the list.

<sup>Its also **not** a good idea to use `list` as a variable name, since it shadows the builtin function [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). Plenty of other suitable names you can use.</sup>

One way is to use a set to keep track of what items you have seen, and only print items that you have seen for the first time:

```
lst = ["5*3*2","5*2*3","2*3*5","2*5*3"]

seen = set()
for exp in lst:
    calc = eval(exp)
    if calc not in seen:
        print(calc)
        seen.add(calc)
```

If you are always dealing with simple multiplying expressions with the `*` operator(no brackets), you could also use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul) instead to multiply the numbers instead of `eval` here. This will first split the numbers by `*`, map each number string to an integer, then multiply every element with each other.

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

lst = ["5*3*2","5*2*3","2*3*5","2*5*3"]

seen = set()
for exp in lst:
    numbers =  map(int, exp.split("*"))
    calc = reduce(mul, numbers)
    if calc not in seen:
        print(calc)
        seen.add(calc)
```

**Output:**

```
30
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following list:

```
l = ['5*3*2','5*2*3','2*3*5','2*5*3', '2*2']
```

(Note that list is already something in python so I wouldn't recommend using that as a variable name)

I would first create a list of unique values:

```
unique_vals = set(map(eval, list))
set([4, 30])
```

Then for each unique values get the first match in l:

```
[next(x for x in l if eval(x) ==  i) for i in unique_vals]
```

I get:

```
['2*2', '5*3*2']
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Hmm   not really,  I have all combinaisons of numbers from my list wih parenthesis , for example  (3+2)*5  or (2+3)*5   or  5*(3+2) or 5*(2+3)   but you see that is the same result, so I would like print only 1 of the 4 elements here

Comment: Isn't that the output I'm showing? Or did you want 30 as an output? I just added 2*2 to show that if you had an extra element it would still work. If  you only want 30, you can stop at unique_vals

Comment: Yes I unterstand but I don't want only 1 value,  because for example if I want 10,  I can do  (5*2)  or 5+2+3, and I need have the 2 differents results,  what I want is more delete the commutativity of operators !

Comment: Ha I see! E.g. if you had 2 * (2 + 3) for 10, you would like to keep it too, but you wouldn't want 2 * (3 + 2). Interesting example :) Not sure how to do this without writing down lots of rules for what defines a == b (but if I was to do this, I'd probably write a class and define the rules in \__eq__ and do (almost) the exact code I showed). I'll be following this post !

Comment: yes exactely !!!  I'm trying it, I think I did it with multiplications only like (2*3*5)=(5*3*2) ...  and I did with + too  but I don't know how do it when I have "+" and "*"  and "/" ... in the same operations ..    Thanks a lot !